# Django Rest Framework append object to many to many field without deleting the previous one

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, manytomanyfield

I am new to **DRF** and could not figure out how to append an object to the **many to many** field  without deleting the previous one.

I am using **PATCH** to update the field MONITORS however the previous value gets substituted by the actual one. I want to append it.

`API GET` is:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "created": "2018-05-02T23:43:07.605000Z",
    "modified": "2021-04-03T10:25:12.280896Z",
    "companies_house_id": "",
    "name": "Ellison PLC",
    "description": "",
    "date_founded": "2018-04-28",
    "country": 4,
    "creator": 7,
    "monitors": [
        3
    ]
}
```

after `PATCH {"monitors":[11]}` I get:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "created": "2018-05-02T23:43:07.605000Z",
    "modified": "2021-04-03T10:25:12.280896Z",
    "companies_house_id": "",
    "name": "Ellison PLC",
    "description": "",
    "date_founded": "2018-04-28",
    "country": 4,
    "creator": 7,
    "monitors": [
        11
    ]
}
```

I want the final GET API to be `"monitors": [3, 11]`

models.py

```
class Company(TimeStampedModel):
    companies_house_id = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    date_founded = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='companies_created'
    )
    monitors = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        blank=True,
        related_name='companies_monitored',
        help_text='Users who want to be notified of updates to this company'
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{0}'.format(self.name)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Company
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = '__all__'

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    companies_monitored = CompanySerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    # companies_moniotred = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'companies_monitored')
```

views.py

```
class CompanyDetailsView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Company.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer


class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = get_user_model().objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = get_user_model().objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


    def get_object(self, username):
        username = get_object_or_404(get_user_model(), username=username)
        return username

    def get(self, request, username):
        username = self.get_object(username)
        serializer = UserSerializer(username)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path

from . import views
from .views import CompanyDetailsView, UserList, UserDetail
urlpatterns = [
    path('details/<int:pk>/', CompanyDetailsView.as_view(), name='company_details'),
    path('users/<str:username>/', UserDetail.as_view(), name='profile_view'),
]
```

Comment: It can be done by overriding the patch method, but I would recommend sending all the many to many object ids in every patch call that way it will not be confusing when a many to many relation was actually deleted and ideally if you want to remove any many to many relation you will be using the patch call again and that will cause the conflict. I hope you get what I am trying to make you understand here.

Comment: @danish_wani: yes I understand and makes a lot of sense, but in case I only want to append and not delete through this API, how can I override the patch method?

Comment: @danish_wani: thanks I will send all the objects id in every patch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use different serializer for `PATCH` method.

```
class CompanyDetailsView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Company.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer
    
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'PATCH':
            return CompanyPatchSerializer
        return self.serializer_class
```

and handle what you need in your serializer

```
class CompanyPatchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = '__all__'

    @transaction.atomic
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        if 'monitors' in validated_data:
            monitor_ids = validated_data.pop('monitors')
            # todo: handle get_or_create
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

I don't like implicit m2m models so my suggestion would be to add [`through`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) model as well.

Comment: thanks as everyone did not recommend the overriding method I decided to add the through model

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend overriding patch method, but below code should do the job

```
def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    request.data._mutable = True
    new_monitors =  request.data.get('monitors')
    existing_monitors = Company.objects.get(kwargs.get('id')).values_list('monitors__id', flat=True)
    all_monitors = existing_monitors + new_monitors
    request.data.update({'monitors': set(all_monitors)})
    return self.partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```